# Poner un valor traido de una bd con select dinamico en un input

Tags: php, mysql

Bueno lo que quiero es lo siguiente tengo una tabla inventario  quiero que al seleccionar un nombre de un articulo se imprima en unos inputs que tengo el valor y la cantidad el valor y cantidad se encuentran en la misma tabla donde hago el select dinamico

de esta manera es como hago un select dinamico para traer los valores

```html
<select  class="form-control select2" class= "form-control" name="dem" id="dem"/>
              <?php  
              if(count($inventario)){
                foreach($inventario as $f){
                  echo "<option value'".$f['fk_referencia_art']. "'>".$f['fk_referencia_art']."</option>";
                }
              }
              ?>
            </select>
```

y tengo 2 inputs

```html
<input type="text" name="cantidad" id="cantidad">

<input type="text" name="precio" id="precio">
```

como puedo hacerlo y muchas gracias

Comment: Para eso necesitas usar AJAX, para hacer la consulta a tu BD y dependiendo que artículo selecciones traigas su cantidad y precio.

Comment: Bienvenido @Illya a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, favoreciendo tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow.

Te mostraré una técnica que puedes usar para estos casos y que te evitará idas y venidas al servidor para obtener datos sobre el mismo elemento, ahorrando así tiempo y recursos.

Consiste en poner esos datos que necesitas en el mismo `select` y luego mostrarlos en los inputs que dices cuando ese `option` sea seleccionado.

Esto se puede hacer de dos maneras, que llamaré *manera antigua*  y *manera nueva*.

#### Manera antigua, antes de HTML 5

Puedes guardar esa información en el `value` de cada `option` con un separador.

Veamos:

```js
document.getElementById('inventario').onchange = function() {
  var elQty = document.getElementById('qty');
  var elPrice = document.getElementById('price');
  /* Dividimos el dato de value usando el separador |*/
  var valParts = this.value.split("|");
  /* Asignamos cada dato a su input*/
  elQty.value = valParts[0];
  elPrice.value = valParts[1];
};
```

```html
<select id="inventario">
  <option value="0|0.00" selected>--Seleccione item--</option>
  <option value="1|50.00">Item 1</option>
  <option value="22|1000.00">Item 2</option>
  <option value="500|9.99">Item 3</option>
</select>
<hr />
<input id="qty"   type="text" placeholder="cantidad" />
<input id="price" type="text" placeholder="precio" />
```

---

#### Manera nueva, después de HTML 5

Puedes valerte de los [*atributos de datos*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/HTML/como/Usando_atributos_de_datos), una poderosa herramienta que te permite guardar en los elementos HTML verdaderas estructuras de datos. Quizá aquí dado que son dos valores y lo hemos trabajado con un separador, se aprecie menos la posibilidad de los atributos de datos. Piensa que aquí puedes guardar por ejemplo todos los datos de una persona como nombre, apellido, fecha de nacimiento, etc y recuperarlos de una forma transparente y ordenada.

Vamos a verlo. Nótese que ha puesto un atributo adicional `ciudad` para mostrar un poco más el alcance de los atributos de datos:

```js
document.getElementById('inventario').onchange = function() {
  /* Referencia a los atributos data de la opción seleccionada */
  var mData = this.options[this.selectedIndex].dataset;

  /* Referencia a los input */
  var elQty = document.getElementById('qty');
  var elPrice = document.getElementById('price');
  var elCity = document.getElementById('city');

  /* Asignamos cada dato a su input*/
  elQty.value = mData.qty;
  elPrice.value = mData.price;
  elCity.value = mData.city;
};
```

```html
<select id="inventario">
  <option value="" data-qty=""    data-price=""        data-city="" selected>--Seleccione item--</option>
  <option value="" data-qty="1"   data-price="50.00"   data-city="Madrid">Item 1</option>
  <option value="" data-qty="22"  data-price="1000.00" data-city="Tokio">Item 2</option>
  <option value="" data-qty="500" data-price="9.99"    data-city="París">Item 3</option>
</select>
<hr />
<input id="qty"   type="text"  placeholder="cantidad" />
<input id="price" type="text"  placeholder="precio" />
<input id="city"  type="text"  placeholder="ciudad" />
```

---

#### ¿Cómo aplicar esto en el contexto de mi programa?

Muy sencillo, haces una sola consulta a la base de datos, trayendo toda la información que necesites en ese momento: `nombre, cantidad, precio` y luego construyes de forma dinámica los `option` del `select`, poniendo dentro los datos, sea mediante el estilo antiguo o el nuevo.

Por ejemplo:

**Estilo antiguo (con separador):**

```
# Plantilla con marcadores
$template='<option value="%s|%s" selected>%s</option>';
# Valor por defecto
$options='<option value=\"0|0.00\" selected>--Seleccione item--</option>';
foreach($inventario as $f){
    $qty=$f['cantidad'];  #Asumiendo que hay una columna cantidad en el SELECT
    $price=$f['precio'];  #Asumiendo que hay una columna precio en el SELECT
    $ref=$f['fk_referencia_art'];
    #Ponemos cada valor en su marcador
    $options.=sprintf($template,$qty,$price,$ref);
}
echo $options;
```

**Estilo nuevo (con atributos de datos):**

```
# Plantilla con marcadores
$template='<option value="" data-qty="%s" data-price="%s">%s</option>';
# Valor por defecto
$options='<option value="" data-qty="" data-price="" selected>--Seleccione item--</option>';
foreach($inventario as $f){
    $qty=$f['cantidad'];  #Asumiendo que hay una columna cantidad en el SELECT
    $price=$f['precio'];  #Asumiendo que hay una columna precio en el SELECT
    $ref=$f['fk_referencia_art'];
    #Ponemos cada valor en su marcador
    $options.=sprintf($template,$qty,$price,$ref);
}
echo $options;
```

Eso te evitará tener que volver a viajar al servidor cada vez que se cambie un `option` y no recargará el HTML, porque tampoco estamos hablando de miles de atributos `data`.

En el código basado en HTML 5 no he puesto ningún dato en el atributo `value` de los `option`, porque la intención era mostrar el alcance de los atributo `data-`, pero en un contexto real, conviene dar uso al atributo `value`, poniendo en él por ejemplo el dato más importante en ese contexto.

Espero te sea de utilidad esta técnica, la cual sirve para sacarnos de apuros y optimizar el código, dándole un buen descanso al servidor. Esto se agradece, sobre todo en conexiones concurrentes. No es lo mismo que miles o millones de usuario soliciten una y otra vez al servidor para pedir una cantidad y un precio, que devolver ese dato a cada uno una sola vez.

Comment: Muchas Gracias Amigo Perfecto

Comment: Probé con éxito la técnica de html5 y funciono muy bien.
¡excelente aporte!
gracias.

Comment: @Rodolfo he mejorado un poco el código, para que quede más limpio, usando `sprintf` y una plantilla con marcadores.