# Traer datos de un input y agregarlos segun su ID

Tags: php, html, base-de-datos

tengo una base de datos con la tabla **"clientes"** la cual necesito que el campo cliente sea igual que la razon social y el RFC lo tome del id de la razon social

```html
<input name="razonsocial" type="text"  autocomplete="off" required title="Completar campo" class="typeahead_2 form-control" <?php
if($_COOKIE["lvl"]==2){
    echo 'value="'. $_COOKIE["usuario"] . '" disabled';
}
?> />
                                        <input id="idCliente" name="idCliente" type="hidden" value="<?php
if($_COOKIE["lvl"]==2){
    echo $_COOKIE["idUsuario"];
}
?>" />
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <h3 style="margin-left:20px;">Beneficiario Preferente</h3>
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Cliente</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-4"><input type="text" name="Cliente" class="form-control m-b"></div> 
                                    
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">RFC</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-4"><input type="text" name="rfc" class="form-control m-b"></div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No entiendo muy bien la pregunta, ¿qué lo jale de donde, que lo ponga donde?

Comment: Que lo jale de la base de datos y que lo ponga en el otro input, que el campo cliente sea igual que la razon social y el RFC lo tome del id de la razon social

Comment: Voy a preguntarte algo: ¿en ese contexto se justifican esas idas y venidas al servidor? ¿no sería mejor traer los datos que necesitas, tenerlos disponibles por ejemplo mediante atributos data y mostrarlos cuando y donde haga falta? Vas a ganar en rapidez, ahorrarás combustible (ir y venir al servidor) y el servidor te agradecerá que no le solicites tanto para esas minucias. [Mira aquí un ejemplo de lo que te digo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/248869/29967), esto puede ser útil para tu caso.