# select dinamico que me lleve inputs

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

Tengo que llenar un select con mi tabla de datos: esta tabla de datos es producto2. En esta tabla tengo nombre, rcf y estado. Al aplicar el siguiente código me muestra los datos en mi  select pero nollena los input.

```
   <script>  
document.getElementById('colaboradores').onchange = function() {
  /* Referencia al option seleccionado */
  var mOption = this.options[this.selectedIndex];
  /* Referencia a los atributos data de la opción seleccionada */
  var mData = mOption.dataset;
  /* Referencia a los input */
  var elCodigo = document.getElementById('rfc');
  var elNombre = document.getElementById('estado');
  /* Asignamos cada dato a su input*/
  elCodigo.value = mData.rfc;
  elDni.value = mData.estado;
};
</script>  
   <?php  
$html="";
if ($productos2) {
    $html.="<select class=\"form-control\" name=\"ONombre\"  id=\"opciones\" onchange=\"function()\" style=\"width: 100%;\">";
    $html.="<option value=\"\" data-rfc=\"\" data-estado=\"\" selected>--Seleccione item--</option>";
    #Aquí declaramos que cada fila se llamará $f
    foreach($productos2 as $f){
       $data="data-rfc=\"{$f->rfc}\" data-estado=\"{$f->estado}\"";  
       $ref=$f->Empresa;
       $html.="<option value=\"$ref\" $data>$ref</option>";
    }
    $html.="</select>";
} else {
    $html.="<p>No hay filas. Revisa la consulta</p>";
}
echo $html;
?>
   </select>
<input id="rfc" type="text" placeholder="rfc" />
<input id="estado" type="text" placeholder="estado" />
```

[Código que usé](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/306182/mostrar-datos-en-campo-de-texto-mediante-un-select/306905#306905)

Comment: Hola, amigo te recomiendo que pases por aquí: [tour] y que te leas estos artículos: [help/dont-ask], [help/on-topic], [help/behavior] y que arregles tu pregunta mirando este articulo: [mcve] tambien puedes pedir ayuda en: [chat]

Comment: y la consulta a la base de datos? Validaste el resultado de la consulta que sea correcta y tenga datos?

Comment: si tiene datos ya valide

Comment: demuestralo en tu post. edita y agrega las pruebas que has realizado. tambien agrega el codigo...

Comment: antes para llenar el select asi eso <select class="form-control" name="ONombre"  style="width: 100% ;">
       <?php  foreach($productos2 as $key =>$value): ?>
         <option> 
           <tr>
                    <td><?php echo  $value->Empresa?>
            </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
       </select>

Comment: joven eso no es lo que le solicite XD

Comment: quise  adaptar este codigo al mio [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/306182/mostrar-datos-en-campo-de-texto-mediante-un-select/306905#306905)

Comment: esta parte del codigo donde la tienes: `$query = $conn -> query ("SELECT * FROM colaborador");` no la veo en tu ejemplo.

Comment: mira te voy a explicar lo siguiente, programar no es como escribir en word y esperar que lo que copiaste y pegaste funcione al tiro, incluso en la adaptacion que estas hacindo tienes que estudiar el codigo y tus necesidades...

y no puedes dejar codigo por fuera sin hacer o utilizar... y mas importante conocer.

Comment: apenas estoy aprendiendo pues esa parte no la pongo ya que estoy asiendo con codeinaiter  tengo un model donde tengo esos datos  esos los  traigo a mi controlador y puedo hacer uso de ellos utilizando el $productos2

Comment: El error de tu codigo (compartido en esta publicacion) es que en tu php no hay una conexion a la base de datos y $productos2 es una variable vacia.... por ende no hay recursos que agreguar los options...

Comment: que te sale si haces var_dump($productos2); en tu controlador

Comment: por que al hacerlo asi me trae los datos <select class="form-control" name="ONombre" style="width: 100% ;"> <?php foreach($productos2 as $key =>$value): ?> <option> <tr> <td><?php echo $value->Empresa?> </tr> <?php endforeach; ?> </select>

Comment: eso que muestras no confirma que los datos lleguen, por so te pedi el var_dump; ahora no te estoy entendiendo si te trae los datos entonces cual es el problema??

Comment: que el primer codigo no tengo agregadas los campos data  y si me muestra los datos en el select . en el segundo codigo agrego los atributos data para poder guardar datos y no tener que hacer uso de ajax  y cunado realizo el agregar mas  atributos data no muestra los campos en el select

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias cosas a corregir en tu código.

En primer lugar, en el `foreach` tú estas usando un elemento `$f` para obtener los valores, pero ese elemento no existe, debes cambiarlo por lo que hayas definido en el `as $variable` cuando abres el bucle. Para adaptarlo llamaremos `$f` al elemento en vez de `$value`.

Por otra parte, te recomiendo que des uniformidad a tu sintaxis, eso evitará confusiones. Por tanto, si usas comillas dobles úsalas en todo. Evita igualmente omitir espacios cuando sean requeridos o dar saltos sin necesidad al crear los elementos.

En cuanto a los `option`, si quieres que te reconozca los `value`, debes poner el dato dentro de los comillas, no fuera. Aquí asumo que el valor que interesa como `value` es `$ref`. Si es otro lo cambias en el código final.

Así debería funcionar:

```
<?php  
    $html="";
    if ($productos2) {
        $html.="<select class=\"form-control\" name=\"ONombre\"  id=\"opciones\" onchange=\"cambioOpciones()\" style=\"width: 100%;\">";
        $html.=\"<option value=\"\" data-qty=\"\" data-price=\"\" selected>--Seleccione item--</option>";
        #Aquí declaramos que cada fila se llamará $f
        foreach($productos2 as $f){
           $data="data-rfc=\"{$f->rfc}\" data-estado=\"{$f->estado}\"";  
           $ref=$f->Empresa;
           $html.="<option value=\"$ref\" $data>$ref</option>";
        }
        $html.="</select>";
    } else {
        $html.="<p>No hay filas. Revisa la consulta</p>";
    }
    echo $html;
?>
```

#### Post-Data

En el código original cierras con una etiqueta `form`, pero dicha etiqueta no abre en ningún momento. Si estás trabajando en el contexto de un `form` conviene poner el código completo.

En la respuesta yo he optado por un código más claro, donde concateno todo en una variable `$html`. Si estás en un `form` esto deberá cambiar en la parte de manejo de error, pero eso no será un gran problema. De todos modos, si hay algo que no entiendes pregunta comentando debajo de la respuesta.

Comment: gracias ya agregue el form para abrir  como se concadenaria todo en una variable para después mostrarlo en los input  edito el codigo

Comment: me manda este msj Mensaje: No se puede usar un objeto de tipo stdClass como matriz

Comment: @Maria parece que `$productos2` es un objeto. Agrega un `var_dump($productos2);` y dinos qué muestra.

Comment: no me muestra nada

Comment: @Maria ¿dónde lo agregaste?

Comment: <form>

<?php  
    $html="";
    if ($productos2) {
       var_dump($productos2);

    }
    echo $html;
?>

</form> me manda todos los datos de la tabla

Comment: array(3) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#31 (47) { ["id"]=> string(1) "3" ["Empresa"]=>

Comment: Pon el `var_dump($productos2);` al inicio, antes del `if`.

Comment: array(3) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#31 (47) { ["id"]=> string(1) "3" ["Empresa"]=> string(6) "BIZNET" ["Asesor"]=> string(0) "" ["nombreorazonsocial"]=> string(67) "APLICACIONES INDUSTRIALES Y COMERCIALIZACIONES ELECTRICAS SA DE CV"  **me manda los datos**

Comment: En efecto, es un objeto y la lectura de objetos se hace con esta sintaxis: `$objeto->propiedad`, revisa la respuesta, he corregido la forma en que se lee `$f`. Aunque en la salida del `var_dump` no veo que haya una propiedad `rfc` ni una propiedad `estado`, las cuales aparecen en tu código original ¿?

Comment: me funciono pero ahora no manda los datos al input

Comment: ¿Qué quiere decir *no manda los datos al input*, @Maria?

Comment: Si no los muestra en el input aún si hay datos en mi base

Comment: gracias @A.Cedano por la ayuda dejo codigo completo por si a alguien le  sirve