# no me aparecen los datos del input pero si el selec

Tags: php, html, select, input

hola comunidad esper me puedan ayudar Tengo que llenar un select con mi tabla de datos: esta tabla de datos es producto. En esta tabla tengo nombre, contactoA y domicilio. Al aplicar el siguiente código me muestra los datos en mi select pero nollena los input.

[use este](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/306182/mostrar-datos-en-campo-de-texto-mediante-un-select/306905#306905)

```
          <script>  
document.getElementById('colaboradores').onchange = function() {
  /* Referencia al option seleccionado */
  var mOption = this.options[this.selectedIndex];
  /* Referencia a los atributos data de la opción seleccionada */
  var mData = mOption.dataset;
  /* Referencia a los input */
  var elCodigo = document.getElementById('domicilio');
  var elNombre = document.getElementById('contactoA');
  /* Asignamos cada dato a su input*/
  elCodigo.value = mData.domicilio;
  elNombre.value = mData.contactoa;
};
</script>  
   <?php  
$html="";
if ($productos5) {
    $html.="<select class=\"form-control\" name=\"ONombre\"  id=\"colaboradores\" onchange=\"function()\" style=\"width: 100%;\">";
    $html.="<option value=\"\" data-domicilio=\"\" data-contactoa=\"\" selected>--Seleccione item--</option>";
    #Aquí declaramos que cada fila se llamará $f
    foreach($productos5 as $f){
       $data="data-domicilio=\"{$f->domicilio}\" data-contactoa=\"{$f->contactoA}\"";  
       $ref=$f->nobreComercial;
       $html.="<option value=\"$ref\" $data>$ref</option>";
    }
    $html.="</select>";
} else {
    $html.="<p>No hay filas. Revisa la consulta</p>";
}
echo $html;
?>
   </select>
<input id="domicilio" type="text" placeholder="domicilio" />
<input id="contactoA" type="text" placeholder="contacto" />
```

Comment: Veo que ya has mejorado un poco, ya te has dado cuenta del id distinto :-)  Otra pista... no uses `data-contactoA` pues parece que no le gustan las mayúsculas en los data-, asi que ponlo en minúsculas en ambos sitios (es decir, en el `data-contactoA` y en el `mData.contactoA`)

Comment: ya edito codigo pero sigue sin darme el dato en input

Comment: Pues ya casi lo tienes... mira mi ejemplo [en este enlace](https://jsfiddle.net/8xpm5kt0/1/) y compara con lo que tu tengas (por cierto, te sobra un </select> pero no creo que sea determinante para que no te funcione)

Comment: ¿que? nada aun?  que no sea el orden en que pones los elementos, pues estas poniendo antes el script que el `echo $html;` y quizás no lo encuentra y no actua

Comment: Efectivamente es el orden, lo acabo de comprobar. Pon todo lo que está dentro de <script></script> al final del archivo (o después del `echo $html;`) y te funcionará. El problema es que cuando haces los `getElementById` dichos elementos aun no estan en el DOM y no los encuentra y aunque los pintes después ya no los busca de nuevo.

Comment: ya gracias quedo gracias

Comment: ok, perfecto pues :-)  Saludos!