# Según valor de un select, completar otros select

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

tengo un `form`, donde cargo los usuarios que tendrán acceso a la web de la empresa, según usuario se le asignara permisos y donde accederá, ya que tiene varios subsitíos. breve resumen: el primer `select` indicara donde accederá:

```
<select class="input_user" name="region" required id="region" disabled style="cursor: not-allowed">
      <option value="" selected="selected"> - selecccionar Acesso - </option>
      <option value="Administrador.php">00 - Dashboard - CAS</option>
      <option value="Neuquen.php">01 - Regional Neuquen</option>
      <option value="comedor_NOC.php">02 - GNOC - BARRA</option>
      <option value="comedor_RDLS.php">03 - RDLS - BARRA</option>
      <option value="comedor_PH.php">04 - PH - BARRA</option>
      <option value="comedor_RIONQN.php">05 - RIONQN - BARRA</option>
      <option value="comedor_AND.php">06 - AND - BARRA</option>
      <option value="comedor_Barrosa.php">07 - BARROSA - BARRA</option>
      <option value="comedor_EFO.php">08 - EFO - BARRA</option>
      <option value="comedor_LLL.php">09 - LLL - BARRA</option>
      <option value="comedor_PlantaArenas.php">10 - Pl.Arenas - BARRA</option>
</select>
```

Y luego tengo otro `select` donde elijo el permiso, que con ese dato diferencio que mostrarle al usuario.

```
    <select class="input_user" name="comedor" required id="comedor" disabled style="cursor: not-allowed">
        <option value="" selected="selected"> - selecccionar permisos - </option>
        <option value="Admin">00 - Administrador</option>
        <option value="Regional">01 - Regional</option>
        <option value="GNOC">02 - GNOC</option>
        <option value="RDLS">03 - RDLS</option>
        <option value="PH">04 - PH</option>
        <option value="RIONQN">05 - RIONQN</option>
        <option value="AND">06 - AND</option>
        <option value="Barrosa">07 - BARROSA</option>
        <option value="EFO">08 - EFO</option>
        <option value="LLL">09 - LLL</option>
        <option value="PlantaArenas">10 - Pl.Arenas</option>
    </select>
```

Mi idea como la lista se va agrandando cada vez mas, es elegir el dato del primer `select` por ejemplo **00 - Dashboard - CAS** y de manera automáticamente se seleccione en el otro `select` el dato que lo vincula que seria **00 - Administrador**. No tengo claro como hacerlo, ya que el proceso de carga debe hacerse antes de enviar el `form`. No tengo mucho conocimiento de JS, si alguien pudiera guiarme y ayudarme, agradeceré mucho!

Comment: Los famosos _selects dependientes_ (o _combos dependientes_). ¿Qué intentaste hasta el momento?

Comment: Como bien dice @padaleiana, podrías usar selects dependientes, incluso, tratándose de algo simple al parecer, podrías usar atributos de datos. [Revisa esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/306905/29967). Se selecciona un identificador y a continuación se muestran datos asociados a ese identificador. Podrías hacer algo parecido.

Comment: me parece que te falta mucho por desarrollar ... lo que presentas es un codigo html muy basico y no hay nada de logicas detras de el o no la has presentado ... te sugiero buscar algun tutorial al respecto y desarrollar mas tus ideas, si algun momento hay un error que no te permite continuar con mucho gusto te ayudaremos de momento me parece que estas pidiendo que te hagan el trabajo ...

Comment: @FranciscoNuñezIALover no pido que me hagan el trabajo.. si leyeras veras que pongo "si alguien pudiera guiarme" y lo hicieron padaleiana y A. Cedano ya que me indicaron como hacerlo, busque y ya lo hice. Ahora pongo como quedo. Es complicado hacer algo cuando no sabes como se llaman, como me dijeron selects dependientes, lo desconocia

Comment: Si es que entendí bien, tu tienes 2 select con códigos y quieres relacionarlos el `00` con el `00`, el `01` con el `01` etc. Al parecer es una relación `1-1`, por lo que tu segundo select sobra absolutamente o hay algo que no entiendo??

Comment: @Yussef es algo que no me di cuenta, pues sobra y ni cuenta me di, entiendo las criticas de varios, pero hace apenas 1 año estoy en programación, y no la tengo tan clara. y en mi sector estoy solo, tuve que aprender de golpe. Así que creo que es normal que cometa errores tontos. Esta web (Stackoverflow) me ayudo muchísimo. Grcias por tu comentario

Comment: No te preocupes es totalmente normal enredarse en un problema. Saludos y suerte en tu proyecto!!

Answer (score -1):

logre hacer lo que necesitaba, así me quedo el código:

Utilice JS:

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
      function dynamicdropdown(listindex)
         {
           switch (listindex)
             {
               case "Administrador.php" :
                  document.getElementById("comedor").options[0]=new Option("00 - Administrador","Admin");
               break;
               case "Neuquen.php" :
                  document.getElementById("comedor").options[0]=new Option("01 - Regional","Regional");
               break;
                                      
              }
               return true;
       }
   </script>
```

PRIMER SELECT:

```
<select class="input_user" name="region" required id="region" disabled style="cursor: not-allowed" onchange="javascript: dynamicdropdown(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
  <option value="" selected="selected"> - selecccionar Acesso - </option>
  <option value="Administrador.php">00 - Dashboard - CAS</option>
  <option value="Neuquen.php">01 - Regional Neuquen</option>
</select>
```

SEGUNDO SELECT:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
   document.write('<select class="input_user" name="comedor" disabled id="comedor" style="cursor: not-allowed"><option value="">- selecccionar permisos -</option></select>')
  </script>
   <noscript>
       <select class="input_user" name="comedor" required id="comedor" disabled style="cursor: not-allowed">
          <option value="" selected="selected"> - selecccionar permisos - </option>
          <option value="Admin">00 - Administrador</option>
          <option value="Regional">01 - Regional</option>
      </select>
    <noscript>
```

Muchas gracias! espero le sirva a alguien.

Comment: Esto no es muy práctico realmente. Además, parecería que necesitas llamar código de servidor, que varía según el caso. Pues tu puedes mandar el tipo de usuario vía Ajax o Fetch y en el servidor decidir en base a eso qué código se va a ejecutar y devolver la respuesta al cliente y/o redirigir a otro sitio. Creo que estás tomando un camino demasiado enrevesado para resolver algo que no es tan complicado, una vez aprendas cómo funciona Ajax o la nueva API Fetch de Javascript.