# Capturar 3 datos de un select - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buenas tengo un select que tiene datos cargado de una base de datos, esto lo estoy que desarrollo en laravel. Lo que necesito capturar de ese select son 3 datos:

```
<div class="col-md-10 mb-2">
                  <label for="tipo_programacion">Tipo Programacion</label>
                  <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="tipo_programacion">
                    <option value="0">SELECCIONAR</option>
                    @foreach($tprogramacion as $tp)
                    <option value="{{$tp->IdTipoProgramacion}}">{{$tp->Descripcion}}</option>
                    <input type="hidden" name="" id="EsAtencion" value="{{$tp->EsAtencion}}">
                    @endforeach
                  </select>
                </div>
```

Del select capturo el value y el texto pero tambien quisiera obtener el tercer dato que esta en el hidden pero al momento de ejecutarlo asi como esta en el ejemplo me carga todo el mal el select. Mi pregunta es: Si puedo agregar un tercer dato al select para dejar de usar el hidden y tambien como llamaria a ese dato con jquery?

```
<script>
var nombre = $('#tipo_programacion option:selected').text();
var id = $('#tipo_programacion').val();
</script>
```

Comment: Puedes poner los datos con un separador en el `value` y luego hacer un  `explode` para obtener los datos diferenciados. O bien puedes usar los atributos `data-` (a partir de HTML5). Creo que [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/248869/29967) te puede ayudar a entender mejor cómo hacerlo.

Comment: @A.Cedano gracias, justo eso era lo que buscaba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer de dos formas:

### Anterior a HTML5

Puedes recurrir a una *astucia* que consiste en usar un separador en cada `value`, por ejemplo:

```
<option value="{{$tp->IdTipoProgramacion}}|{{$tp->EsAtencion}}">{{$tp->Descripcion}}</option>
```

Los valores vendrían así:

```
Valor1|Valor2
```

Luego puedes recuperarlos diferenciados en el servidor usando `explode`.

### A partir de HTML5

Se incorporaron las atributos `data-` que sirven para agregar información adicional a los elementos. Imaginemos que quieres poner no dos, sino 3 ó 5 o 10 datos en una sola opción, harías algo así:

```
<option value="{{$tp->IdTipoProgramacion}}" data-nombre="elNombre"  data-apellido="elApellido" data-direccion="laDireccion">{{$tp->Descripcion}}</option>
```

En este caso, tendrías que recuperar los datos en el cliente, leyendo los atributos `data-` que se han puesto. Aquí pusimos tres: `nombre, apellido, direccion`. Pueden ser más. Sobre la forma de leerlo, puedes [revisar la documentación de MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/HTML/como/Usando_atributos_de_datos).

[En esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/248869/29967) hay un ejemplo completo de aplicación de ambos casos.

Comment: Gracias por ejemplo, lo necesitaba.