# Como llenar un input o cajas de textos a partir de un Select con una base de datos

Tags: php, mysql, html5, phpmyadmin, web

lo que pasa es que quiero saber como poder llenar un sólo input a partir de un select option. Sé específicamente como llenar el select, lo que pretendo saber, es como llenar el campo de texto despues de haber ingresado el valor en el select. En este caso, en una base de datos MySQL, quiero traer el dato del campo "fecha" de la tabla "Faenas", luego ese dato es el que se almacenará en una nueva tabla llamada "Autorizacion" en un campo que también se llama "fecha".

En este caso, llamo los datos que pertenecen a "trabajador_asignado" al select

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego de ese select, es el campo fecha el que necesito que deba llenarse automáticamente después del select, en ese caso el valor fecha de la tabla "Faenas" del usuario "Esteban Larenas" es el que debe insertarse en el campo fecha pero de la tabla "Autorizacion".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este el código del select, no se si debo asignar algo desde ahí primero:

```
<select class="trabajador" name="trabajador_asignado" id="" required>
                            <option value="">Elegir Trabajador</option>
                            <?php
                                include ("./php/conexion_be.php");
                                $quer = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM usuarios");
                                while ($usuar = mysqli_fetch_array($quer)) {
                                ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $usuar[1] ?>"><?php echo $usuar[1] ?></option>
                                <?php } ?>
                    </select>
```

Comment: Este comportamiento lo puedes realizar mediante js y jquery con peticiones ajax

Comment: ¿Por qué no traes el dato ya precargado en el `option`  del `select`? Así evitas constantes viajes al servidor para obtener un solo dato. Podrías usar los atributos `data-` para esos fines.

Comment: Mira [aquí un ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/248869/29967) usando atributos `data-`, (explicado en la segunda parte de la respuesta).

Answer (score 0):

puedes probrar con onchenge en el select y despues llamar la informacion que requieres con una funcion

```
<select class="trabajador" name="trabajador_asignado" id="trabajador" onchange="getFecha()" required>
```

...

```
    <script>
    let getFecha = ()=>{
      var seleccion = document.getElementById("trabajador").value;
      var url = "url del ajax";
      var formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("trabajador", seleccion);
      fetch(url,{
      method: 'POST',
      body: JformData
     })
     .then(res => res.json())
     .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
     .then(r => {
       document.getElementById("inputFecha").value= r.fecha;
     });
    }
    </script>
```

la respuesta es en json, este es con el api de fetch pero al igual puedes ocupar jquery para poder hacer la consulta

Comment: En la respuesta se debería incluir como construir la respuesta desde el backend para que ese json en el frontend se pueda recibir y posterior mostrar

Comment: Por otro lado ¿para qué usar POST, esta petición suena mas a una GET?