# En base a un resultado, ¿cómo hacer otra consulta?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estoy programando un Dashboard de cero en PHP, donde se conecta con una base de datos MySQL. Para las conexiones e inyecciones usamos PDO (por cuestiones estructurales).

La idea es que cuando van a la página correspondiente le cargará una lista con todos los pacientes cargados en dicha tabla, que en este caso se llama "***padronint***". Del lado derecho, hay un icono que debe ejecutar un modal y poder traer datos del paciente pero que están en otra tabla a parte (llamada: "***internacion***).

Según mis conocimientos, el concepto para lograr que traiga esos datos de la otra tabla es que: Mediante su número de identidad (tabla: "padronint", columna: "numdoc"), ejemplo: "1234", compare en la tabla "***internacion***" la columna "historia" (esa columna es igual a la "numdoc", pero con otro nombre) y si las columnas "numdoc" e "historia" tienen el mismo resultado ("1234"), traiga los datos de la tabla internación de "1234".

Adjunto el código de forma organizada y una imagen para entender un poco más la parte técnica.

1era consulta: su función es traer la lista de "***padronint***"

```
  <body>
<section class="home-section">
    <div class="home-content">
      <i class='bx bx-menu' ></i>
      <span class="text">Atencion al Paciente</span>
     </div>
          <?php 

      define("ROW_PER_PAGE",2);

        $search_keyword = '';
        if(!empty($_POST['search']['keyword'])) {
            $search_keyword = $_POST['search']['keyword'];
        }
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM padronint WHERE nombre LIKE :keyword OR numdoc LIKE :keyword OR domicilio LIKE :keyword OR telefono LIKE :keyword LIMIT 5;';
    
        /* Pagination Code starts */
        $per_page_html = '';
        $page = 1;
        $start=0;
        if(!empty($_POST["page"])) {
            $page = $_POST["page"];
            $start=($page-1) * ROW_PER_PAGE;
        }
        $limit=" limit " . $start . "," . ROW_PER_PAGE;
        $pagination_statement = $connect->prepare($sql);
        $pagination_statement->bindValue(':keyword', '%' . $search_keyword . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $pagination_statement->execute();
    
        $row_count = $pagination_statement->rowCount();
        if(!empty($row_count)){
            $per_page_html .= "<div style='text-align:center;margin:20px 0px;'>";
            $page_count=ceil($row_count/ROW_PER_PAGE);
            if($page_count>1) {
                for($i=1;$i<=$page_count;$i++){
                    if($i==$page){ //<li class="page-item active"><a href="#" class="page-link">1</a></li>
                        $per_page_html .= '<li class="page-item"><input type="submit" name="page" value="' . $i . '" class="page-link" /></li>';
                    } else {
                        $per_page_html .= '<li class="page-item"><input type="submit" name="page" value="' . $i . '" class="page-link" /></li>';
                    }
                }
            }
            $per_page_html .= "</div>";
        }
    
        $query = $sql.$limit;
        $pdo_statement = $connect->prepare($query);
        $pdo_statement->bindValue(':keyword', '%' . $search_keyword . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $pdo_statement->execute();
        $result = $pdo_statement->fetchAll();
      ?>
```

A continuación, pondré el código de la barra de búsqueda que filtra una búsqueda específica.

```
      <form name="frmSearch" class="" action="" method="post">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <div class="table-wrapper">
            <div class="table-title">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-8"><h2>Tabla <b>Internados</b></h2></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="search-box">
                            <input type="text" name="search[keyword]" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar&hellip;" value="<?php echo $search_keyword; ?>" id='keyword' maxlength='25'>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Nombre</th>
                        <th>DNI<i class="fa fa-sort"></i></th>
                        <th>Domicilio</th>
                        <th>Telefono</th>
                        <th>Acciones</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <?php
                    if(!empty($result)) { 
                        foreach($result as $row) {
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $row['nombre']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['numdoc']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['domicilio']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['telefono']; ?></td>
                        <td><a class="view" title="View" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#example" value=""><i class="fa-solid fa-eye"></i></a>
                            <!--<a href="#" class="edit" title="Edit" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE254;</i></a>
                            <a href="#" class="delete" title="Delete" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE872;</i></a>-->
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                        }
                    }
                    ?>    
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div class="clearfix">
                <!-- <div class="hint-text">Showing <b>5</b> out of <b>25</b> entries</div> -->
                <ul class="pagination">
                    <li class="page-item"><a href="#" class="page-link"><i class="fa-solid fa-left-from-line"></i></a></li>
                    <?php echo $per_page_html; ?>
                    <!--
                    <li class="page-item active"><a href="#" class="page-link">1</a></li>
                    <li class="page-item"><a href="#" class="page-link">2</a></li>
                    <li class="page-item"><a href="#" class="page-link">3</a></li>
                    <li class="page-item"><a href="#" class="page-link">4</a></li>
                    <li class="page-item"><a href="#" class="page-link">5</a></li>-->
                    <li class="page-item"><a href="#" class="page-link"><i class="fa-solid fa-right-from-line"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
  </form>
</section>
```

Adjunto una imagen para entender la estética del código.
[image: https://i.imgur.com/9ErptEZ.png]

Las columnas que solicito de la tabla "internacion" son: parcontacto, nomcod, domcod, nomgar. Tengo otros pero que por el momento no son tan importantes, podré agregarlos yo por mi cuenta.

Necesitaría saber cómo lograr hacer esa comparación y cuando opriman el ícono les aparezca los otros datos del paciente (ubicados en la tabla de "***internacion***")

```
<td><a class="view" title="View" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#example" value=""><i class="fa-solid fa-eye"></i></a>
```

Muchas gracias por su ayuda y tiempo. Lo valoro un montón.

Comment: Tienes varias soluciones para tu problema. Para empezar, ¿quieres cargar los datos de esos modales durante la carga de la página del panel de control o en el instante en el que pulsar el botón que hace aparecer la ventana modal?

Comment: Hola Oscar, gracias por tu respuesta y por tomarte el tiempo de leer toda la información. Los datos que contiene el modal deberían cargar en el instante que se pulse el botón (el ojo)

Comment: Antes de continuar, deberías cambiar en tu código las apariciones del tipo `<?php echo $row['nombre']; ?>` por `<?= htmlspecialchars($row['nombre']) ?>`. Evitarás que tu página sea vulnerable a [ataques de XSS](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). Para continuar, ¿estás usando jQuery o algún marco de trabajo de javascript similar? ¿o usas javascript puro?

Comment: Muchas gracias por el consejo, es importante saberlo ya que me ayuda a seguir entendiendo más las vulnerabilidades que puede tener el sitio.
 Realmente no me he planteado qué función estoy usando. Tengo el JQuery puesto pero para lo que es este código puntualmente estoy usando javascript puro.

Comment: Desarrollar el funcionamiento va a requerir una reestructuración de tu código bastante grande, por lo que te podría crear una prueba de concepto sencilla para que tú mismo la adaptes a tu código.

Comment: Además, te recomiendo que comiences tu aplicación con una buena base, o bien usando un patrón de desarrollo [MVC](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modelo%E2%80%93vista%E2%80%93controlador) o bien estructurando tu aplicación para facilitar obtener datos (como si fuera a través de un API), ya que si usas peticiones asíncronas (ya sea mediante `jQuery.ajax()`, `fetch` o `XMLHttpRequest`) te va a facilitar mucho el trabajo.

Comment: Podrías tener los datos adicionales pre-cargados usando atributos data- (a partir de HTML 5) y mostrarlos de forma dinámica, eso evitará tener que viajar una y otra vez al servidor en busca de esos datos. Revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/248869/29967), en ella hay un ejemplo de uso de atributos data-.

Comment: Es una buena idea, @A.Cedano, pero justo eso lo he preguntando en el primer comentario. Prefiere que se editen los datos "frescos" y no los que había al cargar la página la primera vez.

Comment: Entiendo @OscarGarcia. No conozco el contexto, pero querer los datos *frescos* sólo tendría sentido si esos datos están cambiando constantemente. Si es así, es evidente que no serviría para este caso el uso de atributos data-. Saludos.

Comment: Si quedan pre-cargados, ¿solo cargaría los datos del resultado? Porque ambas ideas no son malas. El punto es poder llegar al resultado final y que pueda funcionar

Comment: El problema que plantea precargar todos los registros es que en caso de que actives los botones de editar y borrar, a no ser que recargues la página, la siguiente vez que pulses en editar o ver el mismo registro saldrá de nuevo el valor iniciar y no el que editaste. Si quieres te preparo la prueba de concepto para valores precargados y luego decides si quieres hacerlo mediante peticiones XHR.

Comment: Me encantaría que pudieras preparar el concepto. Quiero aclarar un punto muy importante para que no se complique.
 Por el momento no se requiere editar, borrar o agregar ningún dato. Es únicamente que consulte a la base de datos las columnas y la muestre en el modal.
 Reitero, solamente es traer datos para mostrar, no para editar o borrar

Comment: Lo que debe mostrar el modal es el resultado de la consulta. La idea es que en la lista aparezcan los diferentes datos de cada paciente y, que al dar clic al ojo, le abra un modal con datos de ese paciente pero que están ubicados en otra tabla, en este caso es de "internación"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Datos cargados

Esta solución está basada en datos estáticos cargados durante la carga de la página, por lo que una actualización externa de los registros no se reflejaría.

### Volcar los datos en javascript

Para poner los datos a disposición de javascript deberíamos agregar el siguiente código tras la consulta SQL original:

```
/* Consulta SQL original */
$pdo_statement->execute();
$result = $pdo_statement->fetchAll();
/* Volcamos los datos a javascript */
?><script>
    let datos = <?= json_encode($result) ?>;
</script>
```

Ahora tendremos los datos disponibles para trabajar con ellos desde el navegador del cliente cuando los necesite.

### Carga del formulario modal

Ahora necesitamos guardar en HTML el índice del registro que se está volcando en el listado:

```
<tbody>
  <?php if (empty($result) === false): ?>
    <?php foreach($result as $indice => $row): ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?= htmlspecialchars($row['nombre']) ?></td>
        <td><?= htmlspecialchars($row['numdoc']) ?></td>
        <td><?= htmlspecialchars($row['domicilio']) ?></td>
        <td><?= htmlspecialchars($row['telefono']) ?></td>
        <td>
          <a class="view"
            title="View"
            data-toggle="modal"
            data-target="#example"
            data-indice="<?= htmlspecialchars($indice) ?>"
          ><i class="fa-solid fa-eye"></i></a>
          <!--<a href="#" class="edit" title="Edit" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE254;</i></a>
          <a href="#" class="delete" title="Delete" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE872;</i></a>-->
        </td>
      </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
</tbody>
```

Cuando se mezcla PHP con HTML es recomendable usar la [sintaxis alternativa de las estructuras de control](https://php.net/es/control-structures.alternative-syntax) porque mejora la lectura del código y se integra mejor con las etiqueta HTML que el uso de bloques de código delimitados por corchetes.

Además, en el bucle `foreach` extraigo el índice de cada elemento en la variable `$indice` para poder hacer uso de él cuando se pulse en el botón, almacenándolo en el atributo `data-indice` del botón que será pulsado:

```
<a class="view"
  title="View"
  data-toggle="modal"
  data-target="#example"
  data-indice="<?= htmlspecialchars($indice) ?>"
><i class="fa-solid fa-eye"></i></a>
```

### Carga de datos en el formulario modal

Cuando el modal va a mostrarse hay que almacenar en él los datos del registro pulsado:

```
$('#example').on('show.bs.modal', function(evento) {
  let modal = $(this);
  let boton = $(evento.relatedTarget);
  let indice = button.data('indice');
  /* Asignamos a cada campo del modal los valores del registro */
  modal.find('#modal_nombre').val(datos[indice].nombre);
  modal.find('#modal_numdoc').val(datos[indice].numdoc);
  /* ... */
})
```

Donde el HTML del modal debería ser similar a:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="example" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">...</div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="modal_nombre" class="col-form-label">Nombre:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="modal_nombre">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="modal_numdoc" class="col-form-label">Numdoc:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="modal_numdoc">
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">...</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Fíjate que debe coincidir el identificador de cada campo `<input>` del formulario con el que hemos usado anteriormente para cargar los datos en él (`modal_nombre` y `modal_numdoc` en el ejemplo):

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="modal_nombre">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="modal_numdoc">
```

Comment: Ya he colocado en código y funciona de maravilla, mi único problema es que no abre el modal, ¿sabrás por qué?

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir el código completo? Es posible que no hayas cargado el código Javascript de bootstrap (se suele agregar al final del documento).

Comment: Tengo un index que convierte al footer y header en estático. Cuando le das clic a las diferentes páginas lo único que carga es el contenido. El footer y header ya quedan cargados.
 En el footer tengo cargado las funciones de bootstrap dentro de la etiqueta <sciprt>. Te comparto la lista de los mismos: bootstrap.bundle.min.js - popper.min.js - bootstrap.min.js Están en sus versiones más recientes, ¿falta alguno en especial?

Comment: Podría intentar adivinar qué falla o qué falta, pero sin ver el código va a ser difícil y solo voy a poder ofrecer elucubraciones.  ¿Qué versión de bootstrap usas? ¿Podrías exportar el HTML generado? Puedes usar, por ejemplo en Chrome, Control+U para ver el código fuente de la página. Puedes compartir el código en un gist o en cualquier otro sistema colaborativo. Así podré reproducir el problema sin tener que intentar adivinar qué está fallando.